# Issue with express-handlebars new version(6.0.1)

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

```
var express = require('express');
var hbs= require('express-handlebars')
var app = express();
```

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs', hbs({
    layoutsDir: `${__dirname}/views/layouts`,
    extname: `hbs`,
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    partialsDir: `${__dirname}/views/partials`
}))
```

no problem while using version(5.3.4) of express-handlebars
but it's not working with the new version(6.0.1)
it is showing hbs is not a function[TypeError: hbs is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpWGx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars#:%7E:text=install%0A%24%20npm%20start-,Using%20Instances,-Another%20way%20to) there is a new `create` function where you pass your JSON config then define the `hbs.engine` with the `app.engine` function.

Example:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { create } = require("express-handlebars");
const app = express();

const hbs = create({
    layoutsDir: `${__dirname}/views/layouts`,
    extname: `hbs`,
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    partialsDir: `${__dirname}/views/partials`
});

app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);

// Continue code
```